# Primes in Z[i] associated with 1+i

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

How would you prove that an element in $\mathbb Z[i]$ is prime if its associated with $1+i$.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and $u$ is a unit, then $up$ is also prime. From the definition, if $p | ab$ then either $p | a$ or $p | b$. Now what if $up | ab$?

Comment: then either up divides a or up divides b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gauß integer associated with $1+i$ has the same norm, $2$, which is a prime, hence if ir can be factored as $(a+ib)(a'+ib')$, we must have $N(a+ib)=2,\,N(a'+ib')=1$, or vice-versa, so any of its divisors is either a unit or associated with it.